# post relations stuck in sending request

Tags: mysql, go, transactions, foreign-keys, deadlock

Overview of the moment of hit post API:

[image: [enter image description here]]

This my code

```golang
func (s StudentServiceImpl) Create(ctx context.Context, request web.StudentCreateRequest) web.StudentResponse {
    err := s.Validate.Struct(request)
    helper.PanicIfError(err)

    tx, err := s.DB.Begin()
    helper.PanicIfError(err)
    defer helper.CommitOrRollback(tx)

    major, isExistMajor := s.MajorService.FindByMajorName(ctx, request.Major)
    //fmt.Println(isExistMajor)
    if isExistMajor == false {
        major = s.MajorService.Create(ctx, request.Major)
    }

    student := domain.Student{
        Name:      request.Name,
        Age:       request.Age,
        Gender:    request.Gender,
        CreatedAt: time.DateTime,
        Major:     major,
    }

    student = s.StudentRepository.Save(ctx, tx, student)
    studentId := student.Id

    hobbies := s.HobbyService.Creates(ctx, request.Hobbies)
    fmt.Println(hobbies, studentId)
    for i := 0; i < len(hobbies); i++ {
        // todo this below service bug stuck in sending request...
        //s.HobbyService.CreateStudentHobby(ctx, studentId, hobbies[i].Id)
    }
    return helper.ToStudentResponse(student)
}
```

what is wrong, please help me!
link my repo `https://github.com/antoniusbunwiijaya/student-api-go/blob/master/service/student_service_impl.go#L39`

Comment: What do you mean by stuck? Do you have an error stack trace? Could you provide it? Because without more information, it will be hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a deadlock.

If you execute `show engine innodb status;` in the database, you will see something like this:

```
---TRANSACTION 64, ACTIVE 5 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MariaDB thread id 10, OS thread handle 140285377406528, query id 171 172.17.0.1 root Update
insert into student_hobbies(student_id, hobby_id) values(?,?)
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 4891799 ns FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 6 page no 3 n bits 8 index PRIMARY of table `student_api_go`.`students` trx id 64 lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting
```

Here is the call sequence of `(StudentServiceImpl).Create`:

1. it starts an outer transaction.
2. it inserts an record into the table `students`.
3. it calls `(HobbyServiceImpl).CreateStudentHobby`. The sequence of this function is:

   3.1) it starts an inner transaction.

   3.2) it tries to insert a record into the table `student_hobbies`. Here it asks for a record lock on the `students` table due to the foreign key constraint (`FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students(id)`).

   3.3) commit or rollback the inner transaction.
4. commit or rollback the outer transaction.

Step 3.2 can not finished because the outer transaction is not ended yet; but the outer transaction can not end until step 4. So here is a deadlock.

A simple solution to address such kind of issues is to introduce the [Unit of Work pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) into your design. Simply put, for a user action, you create a single transaction for all the services involved (instead of letting each service create its own transaction).

For example, `(StudentServiceImpl).Create` could be the entry of the unit of work. It is in charge of managing the transaction and pass the transaction to the services it calls. I have created [a pull request](https://github.com/antoniusbunwiijaya/student-api-go/pull/1) that uses this solution to address the issue. See more details there.

Please note that this is not necessary the best solution. Transaction has a cost, use it carefully. Maybe you just need transactions for some critical operations. For example, do you really need a transaction for a simple query? See [here](https://github.com/antoniusbunwiijaya/student-api-go/blob/e015f8a5ef682fd318417e632418894cc24314e6/repository/hobby_repository_impl.go#L29-L43) for an example where a simple query is executed in a transaction.